# Mongodb - Take only one element in nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, filter, nested

I'm using mongodb to store my data. My collection consists in a list of objects identified by a type a list of other objects for each of them.

An example of my collection is:

```
[
  {
    "type": "a",
    "properties": [
      {
        "value": "value_a",
        "date": "my_date_a"
      },
      {
        "value": "value_b",
        "date": "my_date_b"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Based on the above data structure, I want to retrieve all collections by a given type, taking for each of them only one element in the nested array (reducing the nested list to a list of only one element).

So, given a type "a", an example of the result may be:

```
[
  {
    "type": "a",
    "properties": [
      {
        "value": "value_a",
        "date": "my_date_a"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I'm started trying this query `{ "type": "a" }` to filter the collections. But, how can I do to take only one "properties" element? I cannot use the "slice" operator.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your reference to slice, that you're not interested in matching a particular nested element, and rather just getting a value at a fixed index (eg, 0).

If you're willing to use the aggregation pipeline, you can use arrayElementAt within a projection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // matches documents with type 'a'
    { $match: { type: 'a' } }, 
    // creates a new document for each
    { $project: { 
        // that contains the original value for type
        type: 1, 
        // and the first element from the original properties for properties
        properties: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$properties", 0 ] } 
    } }
])
```